# Prove the two logic expressions are equal

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Prove $\neg(a \lor b)$ is the same as $(\neg a \land \neg b)$

It makes sense when I think about it, but how does one prove it?

Also is there a relationship with the above and saying: $(a \implies b)$ is the same as its contrapositive $(\neg b \implies \neg a)$ ?

Comment: You can do this with truth tables. For the last part, I don't really think so. However, it is related to the way that you would translate $a \rightarrow b$ and $\lnot(a \rightarrow b)$ using simpler connectives.

Comment: What axioms and rules of inference can we use?

Comment: It does not have a relation with a *conditional* and its *contrapositive*, it is a direct application of [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) instead. For a formal proof of it see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove it, write out a logic table with the four cases for $a$ and $b$.

You can write a similar truth table proof out to show the equivalence of $a \Rightarrow b$ and its contrapositive. See [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020762/is-p-implies-q-implies-lnot-q-implies-lnot-p-always-true). The formal proof (see my answer to the linked question) uses a slightly different construction that the ones you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

We are required to show that
$$¬(a∨b) \vdash (¬a∧¬b)$$

I assume the natural deduction method:

> > 1. $\neg(¬a∧¬b)$, H
> >
> > > 2. $a$, H
> > > 3. $a \vee b$, 2, ∨I
> > > 4. $\neg(a \vee b)$, P
> >
> > 5. $\neg a$, 3,4,¬I
> >
> > > 6. $b$, H
> > > 7. $a \vee b$, 6, ∨I
> >
> > 8. $\neg b$, 4,7 ¬I
> > 9. $\neg a \wedge \neg b$, 2,8 ∧I
>
> 10. $\neg\neg(\neg a \wedge \neg b)$, 1,9 ¬I
> 11. $(\neg a \wedge \neg b)$, 10, DNE

Observe the way we conduct the reasoning by contradiction. Now, can you repeat the proof?

Comment: I think "H" is "hypothesis", but what is "P"?

Comment: @MJD '*P*' stands for "*Premise*", i.e. $¬(a∨b)$ above.

Answer (score 1):

**Truth Table** is my favorite option

[image]

As you can see. LHS=RHS